# What does "cpp-bin" mean in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, ubuntu-12.04

I'm a newbie on linux, I followed [this](http://mjanja.co.ke/2012/04/ubuntu-gcc-4-4-considered-harmful/) to install alternative gcc4.4 on my ubuntu 12.04, but one line of the code confused me:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.4 100
```

Can someone tell me why make a new name `cpp-bin` instead of `cpp` just like this:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-4.4 100
```

I can't find the `cpp-bin` man page. Is this a typo of the author or something new I should learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*cpp-bin* is just a name of your choice. With the above call to update-alternatives you install (something like) a symlink from *cpp-bin* to */usr/bin/cpp-4.4*.

With the second call, you would overwrite the link for the original *cpp* command. Depends on what you want to do.

> alternatives [options] --install link name path priority [--slave link
>   name path]... [--initscript service]

(from: http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)

Comment: Actually i wanted to build andoird and found out it didn't work with the default gcc4.6 in ubuntu12.04,then googled around, found it seems that many people just installed gcc4.4 g++4.4 and did nothing with the "cpp" command, that's why it confused me.